# Trigger an event from the dynamically added button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm facing a issue when I want to trigger an event from dynamically added button.

```
<h1>Image attributes</h1>
<table id="imtbl" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
       <th>SOURCE</th>
       <th>ALT</th>
       <th>TITLE</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="imagetg" value="get line" />
```

Here is the HTML I'm using...

```
$("#imagetg").click(function() {
    var str = $("#t").val();

    alert(str);


    var srres = str.match(/<img(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>/gi);
    alert(srres.length);
    for (i = 0; i < srres.length; i++) {
         var atim0 = $("" + srres[i]).attr("src");
      var atim = $("" + srres[i]).attr("alt");
       var atim1 ="  "+ $("" + srres[i]).attr("title");
      $("#imtbl").append("<tr><td align='center' width='150'>"+atim0+"</td><td align='center' width='150'>"+atim+"</td><td align='center' width='150'>"+atim1+"</td><td><input type='button' value='UPDATE' class='upbtn' id='"+i+"'/></td></tr>");
    }
  });
```

This is the script to add rows dynamically.

```
$(".updt").click(function(){
        var varid= $(this).attr("id");
        alert("Hello"+varid);
    });
```

This is the event I want to trigger when I click on the Update Button. But its not getting triggered, Can someone please assist me to fix this, It will be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: What is `$("#t")` supposed to refer to? I see nothing with an id of `t` anywhere.

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for ur reply... #t is a textarea from which I'm fetching data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for your help...

I got a solution...And now the problem is resolved.

The script we need to use is

```
$("#imtbl").on('click','.upbtn',function(){
           var varid= $(this).attr("id");
            alert(varid);
            });
```

This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#imagetg").click(function() {
var str = $("#t").val();

alert(str);


var srres = str.match(/<img(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>/gi);
alert(srres.length);
for (i = 0; i < srres.length; i++) {
     var atim0 = $("" + srres[i]).attr("src");
     var atim = $("" + srres[i]).attr("alt");
     var atim1 ="  "+ $("" + srres[i]).attr("title");
    $("#imtbl").append("<tr><td align='center' width='150'>"+atim0+"</td><td align='center' width='150'>"+atim+"</td><td align='center' width='150'>"+atim1+"</td><td><input type='button' value='UPDATE' class='upbtn' id='"+i+"'/></td></tr>")
}
$(".updt").click(function(){
    var varid= $(this).attr("id");
    alert("Hello"+varid);
});});
```

Comment: Hi Ashish, Thanks for ur reply... #t is a textarea from which I'm fetching data